# Laravel 5.5 - Query on multiple conditions but only if POST data equals 1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

First of all, let me just say I have little code to show as I'm trying to work out how this would be possible.

**My scenario:**
I have a form that users can check skills that they wish to search by. A simple boolean for each skill (either 0 or 1, 1 being true of course).

I need to query a `skills` table using this data, and pull out the corresponding profile but only if a profile's skill column matches **at least one of** the chosen skills.

I have tried something like this:

```
$partners = DB::table('skills')
        ->when($start_up_finance, function ($query) use ($start_up_finance) {
            return $query->where('start_up_finance', $start_up_finance);
        })
        ->when($market_research, function ($query) use ($market_research) {
            return $query->where('market_research', $market_research);
        })
        ->get();
```

However `when` doesn't work how I thought it would.

Can this be achieved with a simple `where/orWhere` combo? Am I just overthinking it? I'll be using the `distinct` method to ensure no duplicate profiles show

Comment: Do you actually have separate columns for each skill?  If so, then you have a bigger problem at hand.  The ideal structure for your data would be to have multiple records for each skill, for each person.  Then, just aggregate over all people and query your result.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah there's 10 columns, one column for each skill. The row is then attached to a profile via relationship. I couldn't think of a better way of doing it. Happy to listen to suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal structure for your `skills` table would be a normalized one where each user-skill resides in a separate record.  Something like this:

```
user_id | skill
1       | start_up_finance
1       | market_research
1       | accounting
2       | market_research
```

Now supposing you wanted to obtain all users who had either start up finance or accounting skill.  You could just use the following simple MySQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM skills
WHERE skill IN ('start_up_finance', 'accounting');
```

This would only return the first user in this example.  I use `SELECT DISTINCT` here to remove duplicates which are just artifacts.

The reason why storing each skill in a separate column is not ideal is manyfold.  But top of the list is that each time you add a new skill requires a fairly intrusive database change.  The normalization problem is the other major issue.  Databases are designed to efficiently do operations with sets of rows, not really columns.

Here is my attempt at a Laravel query:

```
users = DB::table('skills')
    ->distinct()
    ->select('user_id')
    ->whereIn('skill', ['start_up_finance', 'accounting'])
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm going to attempt to restructure my database haha